# Draw images in limited region

Tags: xaml, directx, draw, xps, region

Hello i am coding something like .xps viewer.
structure of xps file containts  objects which represents shape(f.e triangle) and then  have got  inside it. objects represents images.
example structure is

```
<canvas shape="....">
   <path src="a.jpg"/>
   <path src="b.jpg"/>
</canvas>
```

i would like to draw this two images but only in area limited by it parent node(canvas)
i converted images into Bitmaps.
Canvas shape is represented by set of points.
I am going to draw this in directx.
Thanks for advices
Yours sincerely,
Przemek

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers if they solved your problem. Otherwise, no one is going to answer your questions soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stencil buffer for this.

First, draw the canvas' shape in the stencil buffer (setting values to 1). Then change settings to only draw where stencil value is equal to 1 and draw the other shapes. Finally, clear the stencil buffer for further usage.